# How to merge/ rename factor levels in R

Tags: r, levels

I have a matrix of `dim(37,18)`. My aim is to get the first column and convert it into a factor with thre levels.

This is what I did :

```
> YY <- ND[,1] # ND is the matrix
> class(YY)
[1] "character"
> YY <- as.factor(YY)
> class(YY)
[1] "factor"
```

the output I get:

```
> YY
 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10  V2  V3  V4  V5  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 
 S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  A1  A2  A3  A4  E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6  E7  E8  E9 E10 E11 E12 E13 E14 E15 E16 E17 E18 E19 E20 E21 
 V23 V24 V25 
 E22 E23 E24 
37 Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 E1 E10 E11 E12 E13 E14 E15 E16 E17 E18 E19 E2 E20 E21 E22 E23 E24 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 ... S9
```

I want the output as:

```
> y
[1] S S S S S S S S S A A A A E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
Levels: A E S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the numbers

```
y <- factor(sub("\\d+", "", YY))
y
#[1] S S S S S S S S S A A A A E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
#Levels: A E S
```

#### data

```
YY <- structure(c(29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 16L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L
), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", 
"V10", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", 
"V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", "V25"
), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "E1", "E10", "E11", "E12", 
"E13", "E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18", "E19", "E2", "E20", 
"E21", "E22", "E23", "E24", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", 
"E9", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9"), class = "factor")
```